# Winforms - getting Cross-thread error on picturebox image attribute

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm using [SharpAdbClient](https://github.com/quamotion/madb) and I register an event called `OnDeviceConnected` which fires when a device is plugged in to the PC where my form is running on.

When a device is connected and this event is fired, I'm trying to set a PictureBox image like so:

```
void OnDeviceConnected(object sender, DeviceDataEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    imgBootFlashState.Image = Properties.Resources.locked; // CRASHES
    helpBootState.Image = Properties.Resources.help_boot_flash_disabled; // CRASHES

    ...
}
```

This attempt throws this error:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MainForm' accessed from a thread 
other than the thread it was created on.
```

I have no idea where this "other" thread came from, since it didn't came from me, **BUT** If I'm changing the PictureBox's `BackgroundImage` like so:

```
void OnDeviceConnected(object sender, DeviceDataEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    imgBootFlashState.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.locked; // WORKS
    helpBootState.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.help_boot_flash_disabled; // WORKS

    ...
}
```

It works fine.

How can it be? What is the deal with this error?
I know I can just solve it by using the `BackgroundImage` property, but I want to understand what throws this error...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the winfom controls from other thread, try this :

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                           imgBootFlashState.Image = Properties.Resources.locked;
                           helpBootState.Image = Properties.Resources.help_boot_flash_disabled; 
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imgBootFlashState.Image = Properties.Resources.locked;
                        helpBootState.Image = Properties.Resources.help_boot_flash_disabled;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Well, this answer is fine but my issue was that I used a 3rd party Nuget and it seems that it uses a worker thread so my MainThread was still active, as I found out, so I wrapped it with a background worker of my own and user the Invoke method. [Control.Invoke is hanging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078175/control-invoke-is-hanging)

Comment: Good to know that you discovered the issue.